# dotnet core publish issue

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core

I'm trying to publish my site dotnet core 2.2 in Linux Ubuntu. 
After publish, I execute dotnet and get this result:

[image]

and my IP public is:

[image]

but when I tried to access the url "187.72.167.144:5000" in browser I get "Connection Refused"

Somebody know what is wrong?

Obs: I have a PHP site running on apache with port 80 in this server and work fine. I dont know if this interfere

Comment: Check the port 5000 is opened (https://www.meziantou.net/2017/04/25/publishing-an-asp-net-core-website-to-a-linux-host#step-5-configure-the). If you use ufw: `sudo ufw allow 5000/tcp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is listening **localhost** not 187.72.167.144, try use

```
env ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000 dotnet Retrix.API.dll
```

Now, your application is listening any address bound to your computer.

Comment: Solve my problem. Thank You.

So, can you explain in detail? what is "env ASPNETCORE_URLS" does? 

Thank You again!

Comment: env - run a program in a modified environment. AspNetCore's `CreateDefaultWebHost()` can read the environment variable "ASPNETCORE_URLS" then set listening address and port to its value. More details about `env` can be found by running `man env`.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with the following command: `dotnet Retrix.API.dll --urls=http://187.72.167.144:5000`